# How do i print this Alphabets in this pattern/output : a B c D e F g H i J k L m N o P q R s T u V w X y Z

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

Using anyloop how will i print the code in a
Small and Big Pattern like this : a B c D e F g H i J k L m N o P q R s T u V w X y Z

```
System.out.println("Aphabets In Small And Big Letter Pattern");  
// Responsible for Small Letters
for(SLet = 'a'; SLet < 'z'; SLet++){  
while(SLet%2!=0)
    {  
        System.out.print(SLet+ " ");
        SLet++;}
    }

System.out.println();
// Responsible for Big Letters
for(BLet = 'A'; BLet <= 'Z'; BLet++){  
while(BLet%2!=1)
    {  
        System.out.print(BLet+ " ");
        BLet++;}`}
    }`

    
// Combination of Small and Big Letter
```

// Outcome is like this: a B c D e F g H i J k L m N o P q R s T u V w X y Z

Comment: Hint: `Character.toUpperCase(char ch)` and possibly `Character.toLowerCase(char ch)` as well or instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me : (if even, write to lower case)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (char SLet = 'A'; SLet < 'Z' + 1; SLet++) {
            char toPrint = SLet;
            if (SLet % 2 != 0)
                toPrint = Character.toLowerCase(toPrint);
            System.out.print(toPrint + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```